# Liaison avec voyelles nasales

Tags: liaisons, nasalisation, h-aspiré

1) Y a-t--il une différence phonétique entre **un air** et **un nerf** ?

2) Dans les cas ci-après la liaison est obligatoire ?
**Un ami**,  **aucun ami**, **bien aimé**, **rien à dire**

3) Il n'y a pas de liaison avec *en* dans l'expression **en haut**. La raison est que haut commence avec *h aspiré* ?

4) Y a-t-il une différence phonétique entre **bon élève** et **bonne élève**, **bon ami** **et bonne amie** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) non
2) oui, oui, ça dépend<sup>1</sup>, facultative
3) oui (On peut l'appeler *h disjonctif* car il n'est pas prononcé, donc pas aspiré non plus).
4) non, non

<sup>1</sup> Mon bien-aimé : liaison obligatoire, J'ai bien aimé le film: facultative.

Comment: Merci vivement. Je pense pouvoir comprendre et maîtriser les nuances du français grâce à vos réponses☺!

Comment: Au fait, juste une question : dans votre réponse vous écrivez << donc pas inspiré >>. Est-ce possible de remplacer pas avec non ici ?

Comment: Non, *non* ne remplace pas *pas*. Je ne peux pas écrire *il n'est non prononcé*. En revanche, *il est non prononcé, donc non aspiré (aussi)* aurait été possible, mais ça ressemble plus à des maths qu'à du français.

Comment: Merci. C'était ma faute. Bien sûr pas ne peut pas remplacé par non ici. J'aurais dû être plus précis. J'avais réfléchi à la citation << Le clerc, non moins étonné, salua le colonel >> (Balzac). Ici, la négation se base à non. Mais, je comprends la différence.

Answer (score -1):

Il y a bien une différence phonétique entre **bon élève** et **bonne élève**, **bon ami** et **bonne amie**
A l'oral la différence s'entend même si elle est minime.

Comment: Je ne suis pas francophone avec le français comme langue maternelle. Moi, je n'arrive pas à entendre aucune différence phonétiquement. Pour cela, j'ai posé la question. Merci pour ta réponse.

Comment: @dimitris Il n'y a **aucune** différence phonétique. Il est absolument impossible de distinguer à l'oreille (ou même avec une analyse numérique d'un enregistrement audio) si quelqu'un a dit *bon après-midi* ou *bonne après-midi*.

Comment: Du coup, actuellement, j'ai accès à l'ouvrage exercices systematiques de la prononciation française et c'est exactement ce que l'on y lit (évidemment je n'avais eu aucune doute après avoir vu ta réponse ☺).

Comment: @dimitris Je n'ai pas de doute la dessus mais ce serait bien que tu dises à qui tu t'adresses dans tes commentaires. Tout le monde n'a pas forcément accès à l'ouvrage *Exercices systématiques **de prononciation** française* (pas *de **la** prononciation française*).

Comment: @jiliagre. Oui, tu as raison. Merci pour ton commantaire. Au fait, tu as vu de nouveau mon souci avec les articles. Pourquoi de et pas de la ?

Comment: @dmitris C'est "de prononciation" parce que la prononciation ne possède pas les "Exercices systématiques" -- elle les décrit.